# force .NET windows app. to display numbers in english shape

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, culture

I am building a culture specific .NET windows application and recently I faced a problem with the number shape which changed according to the OS culture. for example if the OS culture is English (United States) and run the application, the displayed numbers will be in english shape (the usual one we used to), but if I changed the windows culture to Arabic-SaudiArabia the numbers will be shown in different shape.

I want to force this application to display numbers in the english shape only whatever the culture is.

I searched the internet and tired many solutions which try to change the application Culture and UICulture without any result.

regards,

Comment: Where is your code? Where and how are you showing the numbers?

Comment: dim originalNumber As Double = 9876543210.0123444
Label2.Text = originalNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the culture to use when doing your string conversion, e.g:

```
Dim i As Integer = 5
Dim s As String = i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: I see from your other comments that you're using Visual Basic - I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

use below code in behind code:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
        ci.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = DigitShapes.None;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`culture.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution=System.Globalization.DigitShapes.None;`

Comment: Hi,
I tried it as below, but it doesn't change any thing. Please try it with the following scenario:
In regional settings, change Format to Arabic-SaudiArabi and from additional settings set use native digits to national, then try below code...


originalNumber = 12345
Dim cu As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("en-US", True)
cu.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = System.Globalization.DigitShapes.None
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cu
Label2.Text = originalNumber

Comment: @mohammadabukhamseh simply setting the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");` is working as you expect in WPF, while in Winforms it not the case. I guess the controls in Winforms doesn't support digit substitution

Answer (score 0):

Change it in registry directly.
Like that for English shape:

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International", "sNativeDigits", "0123456789")
```

For Arabic shape:

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International", "sNativeDigits", "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩")
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International", "NumShape", "2")
```